# Sound is gone, I don't know why

Tags: sound, 15.04, lubuntu

I installed all the recommended packages in Synaptic Package Manager and now my sound is gone.

Before installing all packages sound was working perfectly.

I'm using Defender Bravo HN-880 headphones and they are working perfectly, I tested them on my phone.

Sound isn't muted in `alsamixer` and videos what I trying to watch.

OS: Lubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `pavucontrol` and check that you device is not muted or set "Input only" there.

Comment: It is different from alsamixer.

Comment: it isn't muted in alsamixer but i'il try this

Comment: thanks, that's programs shows that was my headphones muted but alsamixer not :D

Comment: but when i'm trying listen to music i can't hear it but pavucontrol show music that sound is coming edit k i fixed just need to change sound card was player using..

Comment: Alsamixer is for alsa what pavuc is for pulse. They are one on top of other. The DE sound settings are usually a crippled version of pavuc.

Comment: Check that you device is default and configured for output.